# Error creating MongoTransactionManager bean in spring-data-mongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to add transactional support in MongoDB with spring-data-MongoDB. But I am unable to create a bean of MongoTransactionManager which is necessary to add transactional support.

My code -

```
@Configuration
public class MongoTransactionsConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration{
    @Bean
    MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDbFactory dbFactory) {
        return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
    } 

    @Override
    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "backend";
    }

}
```

I am following https://spring.io/blog/2018/06/28/hands-on-mongodb-4-0-transactions-with-spring-data

This is the error I receive-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.observeai.platform.integration.backend.da.config.MongoTransactionsConfig] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:599) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:726) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:667) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:635) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:420) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:390) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:511) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1198) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:889) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:875) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:861) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:810) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at com.observeai.platform.integration.backend.web.App.main(App.java:18) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mongodb/MongoTransactionManager
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
... 20 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoTransactionManager
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
... 24 common frames omitted
```

**Versions I am using -**

**MongoDB - 4.0.0**

**Spring Data MongoDB - 2.1.0.RC1**

**MongoDB Driver - 3.8.0**

Comment: Are you using Maven? It may have corrupted a jar when it downloaded it. Try clearing its cache and rebuilding your app.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I tried clearing the cache but the same problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Successfull supported versions. Use Spring boot version `2.1.5.RELEASE`
Please download latest MongoDB Java driver from [MongoDB Java Driver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver) or use below maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Spring data MongoDB**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
   <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

**MongoDB**: 4.0.9